# What's the exact meaning of "flat eyes"?

Tags: meaning

In the American novels, there are a lot of expression of this 'flat eyes'.

Seemingly not very favorable expression, but what's this phrase insinuating exactly?

I am  not a native speaker of English.

Comment: It always helps to provide some context, say, an excerpt where this phrase appears.

Comment: Most of the Google Books hits for "flat eyes" are about insects or potatoes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Flat*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flat) usually refers to dull and emotionless.

> lacking interest or emotion; dull and lifeless; lacking vitality or animation.

It is often misused, I had to look for a while to find a good example, and this was the best I could do (it's not even a good sentence!)

> Maybe because his *flat eyes* had no expression and he was squinting at me like a mob character.

Flat can similarly refer to *affect*, *scenario*, *food* or *joke*.